# BER vs Eb/N0 for BPSK signal with depth of modulation 120 degrees (+-60 degrees)

Tags: matlab, modulation, bpsk

I want to draw graph of function BER vs Eb/N0 for BPSK modulation with depth of modulation is from –60 to 60 degrees (or from 0 to 120 degrees). Can I use for that MatLab's tool 'bertool', or I need to use something else?

Thank you!

Comment: My standard advice to beginner students is to avoid using Matlab's toolboxes. Do it the hard way the first few times and, once you understand what is going on, use the toolbox to save time if you want.

Comment: Thank you for advice, you are right of course, but for me is very interesting tools for it, may be function or object in MatLab with this parameter.